# code to set legacy mode in webconfig file through c#.net

Tags: asp.net, xhtml

how to set the  `<xhtmlConformance mode="legacy"/>` tag in web.config  as  "strict" using the codes  in c#.net for an asp.net webaplication

Comment: I have no idea what your question means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna have to go with Mitch on this one... "What?"  If you are asking how to get at this value programmatically... You *did* try Google first, right?

```
System.Web.Configuration.XhtmlConformanceMode
```